# Как выравнивать блоки по центру не сломав wrap?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, flexbox

Допустим есть блоки

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background: #fff;
}

.box {
  width: 170px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: dashed 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы последние блоки прижимались к левому краю, но при этом чтобы вся конструкция блоков была по центру, т.е. будто там указан `justify-content: center`.

Можно задать фиксированную ширину, но проблема в том что `.main` резиновый.

На [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tq4wx1cu/) это хорошо видно.

Если уменьшать или увеличивать область отображения то будет работать warp, но при этом справа будет много свободного пространства

Comment: А имеет ли значение порядок блоков? Что если вместо горизонтального направления использовать вертикальное?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 170px);
  max-width: 890px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: dashed 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Интересный вариант. Стоит учитывать http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: Да, я просто не думаю, что флексами такое удастся побороть в принципе.

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант

```css
*,
:before,
:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background: #fff;
}

.box {
    width: 170px;
    height: 130px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: dashed 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin: 10px;
}

.box:empty {
    height: 0;
    border: none;    
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Интересно. Лучше вместо `margin: 0 10px;` сделать `margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;` - чтобы было только одно место для изменения отступов, а не два.

Comment: @Qwertiy поправил

Answer (score 2):

Можно обернуть блоки в еще один блок которому задаешь `justify-content: flex-start;` и изменять его ширину через `@media`, а блоку `.main` задать `justify-content: center;`

Comment: media не умеет остатки от деления